# html tags in report PDF from HTML in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a laravel project where I need to print a pdf. I made the printing without problems, using a library DOMPDF, but inside the pdf i need to print a content of a Rich Text Area.

The UI:

[image]

The output is

```
Note
<p><b>Test</b></p><p><b><br></b></p><ul><li><b>Test 1</b></li><li><b>Test 2</b></li></ul><p><br></p>
```

The blade page have:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h4>Note</h4>
            {{$plan->note}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can i print the html content correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Laravel does html entity encoding when you print something using `{{ $plan->note }}`.

In order to not to encode HTML elements, you have to use

```
{!! $plan->note !!}
```

This is not only for PDF. It can be used for web page rendering as well.